# Validation to not allow both fields to be used issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `Price` model with 4 different fields:

```
t.decimal  "amount"
t.decimal  "amount_per_unit"
t.decimal  "unit_quantity"
t.string   "unit"
```

I'm trying to make a custom validation that allows either the `amount` or `amount_per_unit`  fields (this includes `unit quantity` and `unit`) to be filled but not both of them. So to make a word diagram of what I mean.

```
amount = YES
amount_per_unit + unit + unit_quantity = YES

amount_per_unit (alone or amount.present) = NO
unit_quantity (alone or amount.present) = NO
unit (alone or amount.present) = NO
amount and amount_per_unit + unit + unit_quantity = NO
```

if you still are confused, just know that its either the amount itself thats filled in or the amount per unit fields that are (1 or 3).

So far I tried this validation in my `Price` model:

```
validates :amount, :numericality => true                                
validates :amount_per_unit, :numericality => true       
validates :unit_quantity, :numericality => true
validates :unit, :inclusion => UNITS

validate :must_be_base_cost_or_cost_per_unit

private

  def must_be_base_cost_or_cost_per_unit
    if self.amount.blank? and self.amount_per_unit.blank? and self.unit.blank? and self.unit_quantity
        #   one at least must be filled in, add a custom error message
        errors.add(:amount, "The product must have a base price or a cost per unit.")
        return false
    elsif !self.amount.blank? and !self.amount_per_unit.blank? and !self.unit.blank? and !self.unit_quantity
        #   both can't be filled in, add custom error message
        errors.add(:amount, "Cannot have both a base price and a cost per unit.")
        return false
    else
        return true
    end
  end
```

This validation doesn't work though as all fields are blank it results to a `numericality` error and if I fill all of them, it creates the price with all fields filled. What needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your values are coming in as nil, not blank.

Try changing the second condition to:

```
elsif !self.amount.to_s.blank? and !self.amount_per_unit.to_s.blank? and !self.unit.to_s.blank? and !self.unit_quantity.to_s.blank?
```

Also, it seems you have a typo on the last condition on both statements (e.g.    !self.unit_quantity  instead of !self.unit_quantity.to_s.blank?

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo. It was the `blank` not at the end of the unit_quantity.